# why use lookup transformation instead of just a source file with joiner?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

so i'm learning informatica powercenter

(at least through cloud designer)

i'm trying to figure out why we would use a lookup transformation to retrieve data based on a key, when we can just use a source transformation and join the data based on the key

i did both situations and they both accomplished the same thing using 2 different tables (flat files, csv)

why would i use a lookup transformation (besides having 1 transformation instead of 2 (source + joiner))

Comment: If you have 2 ways to do the same thing time both (multiple trials) and use the faster.

Comment: If you need to retrieve data from multiple tables, lookups usually allow to create a more readable mapping. However, in case of a large lookup table joiner will provide a better performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of lookup transformation which solve some particular scenarios. Those cannot be done using a joiner. For example, unconnected lookup, un-cached lookup, dynamic cache lookup, active and passive lookups have their unique uses

Comment: I'd add the possibility to use unequal condition with lookup - one cant do that with joiner.

Answer (score 0):

One big advantage of the Lookup transformation is the disconnected mode:

- You can perform the Lookup based on a condition
- You can also use the same lookup several times on several fields (e.g. you want to retrieve the name of two different customers, the payer and the ship-to, from the same dimension table)

More generally (i.e. not specific to the unconnected Lookups):

- You can perform a Lookup on an inequality, which is not possible with the Joiner (e.g. retrieve the status of the customer at the current date, having a begin and end of validity date in the lookup table)
- You can retrieve the first / last value based on the sort criteria if there are more than one record satisfying the Lookup condition

This comes in addition to what has already been said: better readability, especially in case of multiple Lookups, Dynamis Lookup Cache, etc.

Hope this helps :)